# D3.js Radial Tree 1 issue

Tags: loops, d3.js, tree, parent, children

I've created a Jsfiddle [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/KenHart/hy6m4uan/16/)

Holding a mouse over a node gives you 4 options, green - add, red- remove yellow and blue do other things - dont worry about those.

I will explain what this does - when you press the "save" button it steps through every instance of the tree using the children.map function. This returns the Parent and child which is what I need ideally.

```
var onClick = function() {

d3.selectAll('g.node')  
.each(function(p){
p.children.map(function(c) {        
    alert( c.name +"("+ c.id+")"+ "- PARENT TO -" + p.name + "(" + p.id +")" 
)
     });    
});

};
```

If I change it to:

```
d3.selectAll('g.node')

.each(function(p){
alert( p.name  )

});
```

It will go through all the names but I cannot get the parent and child details regardless of calls to the map.

**This** doesnt always work, its hit and miss - if you add a few nodes you'll soon see, this is the bit I cannot resolve.

I know the code could be cleaned up and I am SURE there are a few bits where you will sit and think WTF is he doing!! Please feel free to point them out as I'm trying my best to learn.

Thank you for your time in reading this and for any help or code mod.

Answer (score 0):

After a little "tweaking" and a MAJOR amount of help from Bruno Fenzel the code now works !!

[Working code here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54900873/d3-js-child-map-failure-any-gurus-spot-my-error)